# × react TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I think I just need another pair of eyes on this, because I can't get what I'm missing here.
in server,the code is:

```
function getByCategory (token, category) {   return new Promise((res)
  => {
let posts = getData(token)
let keys = Object.keys(posts)
let filtered_keys = keys.filter(key => posts[key].category === category && 
!posts[key].deleted)
res(filtered_keys.map(key => posts[key]))   }) }
```

in postAPI,the code is:

```
export const getByCategory=(category)=>{
fetch(`${api}/${category}/posts`,{headers})
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(data=>data)
};
```

in categiries:

```
  PostsAPI.getByCategory(category).then((posts) =>{
            posts.map((post)=>{
                return addPosts(post)
            });
        });
```

my code was pushed at https://github.com/tulipjie/redux-readable
I hope someone can help me.thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method doesnt return anything.
Try putting "return" in front of **fetch** like so:

```
export const getByCategory=(category)=>{
    return fetch(`${api}/${category}/posts`,{headers})
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(data=>data)
};
```

Or remove curly braces like so:

```
export const getByCategory=(category)=>
    fetch(`${api}/${category}/posts`,{headers})
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(data=>data);
```